# Iterate in blade json data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

im trying to iterate in a foreach loop a json object, but with no success, it keeps giving me error regarding html entities.

The data im trying to output in my foreach is above:

Data:
variable that is stored the data above is '$product->tags['data']'

```
{"tags":[{"type":"circle","points":[[1.0449999570846558,0.5450000166893005],[0.9850000143051147,0.4399999976158142]],"popup":{"title":"my title","description":"my description"}},{"type":"rectangle","points":[[0.03500000014901161,0.125],[0.3400000035762787,0.6000000238418579]],"popup":{"title":"roupa","description":"guardar roupa"}}]}
```

My code:

```
@foreach($product->tags['data']->tags as $tag){
{{$tag->type}}
}
```

My error:
Invalid `argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Make sure `$product->tags['data']->tags` is array.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $product->tags['data'] = '{"tags":[{"type":"circle","points":[[1.0449999570846558,0.5450000166893005],[0.9850000143051147,0.4399999976158142]],"popup":{"title":"my title","description":"my description"}},{"type":"rectangle","points":[[0.03500000014901161,0.125],[0.3400000035762787,0.6000000238418579]],"popup":{"title":"roupa","description":"guardar roupa"}}]}';
    $product->tags['data'] = json_decode($product->tags['data'], true);

    foreach($product->tags['data']['tags'] as $tag)
        echo $tag['type'].'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json is:

```
$json='{"tags":[{"type":"circle","points":[[1.0449999570846558,0.5450000166893005],
[0.9850000143051147,0.4399999976158142]],
"popup":{"title":"my title","description":"my description"}},
{"type":"rectangle","points":[[0.03500000014901161,0.125],
[0.3400000035762787,0.6000000238418579]],"popup":{"title":"roupa","description":"guardar roupa"}}]}';
```

I assume that you are not decoding the `json` when you pass it to the view, so you gotta do it in your controller:

```
return view('sample')->with('data',json_decode($json));
```

**json_decode** is the function to decode your json data to be iteratable in blade.

Now, in your blade template, you can loop through the tags like this:

```
@foreach($data->tags as $tag)
  {{$tag->type}}
  <br/>
@endforeach
```